# Unable to permanently change selector with jquery due to page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links to pages on my site. I want the links to change how they look (become bold) when the user clicks on them. I have set a default value for the "Home" link so when a user first goes to the website the "home" link is bold. The problem is, whenever another link is clicked I can see that it changes very briefly to bold, but then defaults back to the "Home" link being bold, since that is the default value that is hard-coded in to the website. How can I change this so that the link that is made bold is the link of the page the user is currently on (not always defaulting back to the "Home" link being bold)? Thanks so much for any assistance!

Here is the html:

```
<table class="sidebar_table">
    <tr class="option">
        <td class="select selected">image</td>
        <td><a href="my_website_link">A Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jquery code I'm using:

```
$('tr.option').click(function () {
$('tr.option td.select').removeClass('selected');
$(this).find('td.select').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Something wrong with CSS `:visited`? It's existed for... a _long_ time. You don't have to do everything with jQuery, y'know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Y'know, he never said there was anything *wrong* with it. Sometimes people just forget about things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I don't think he wants all links the user has visited to be in bold, only the link associated with the current document.  So I would expect the solution to be either implemented server-side (optimal), or with Javascript and a check of the `location.href`.

Comment: @mblase75: It's called rhetoric

Comment: @Danimal37: On reflection, I may have misinterpreted the question. I think circusdei got it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps, but it came across as condescension.

Comment: Yes: "I don't think he wants all links the user has visited to be in bold, only the link associated with the current document."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) You could detect which page the user is on with php, and write the classes that way.

Option 2) If you don't want to use PHP, you can use a document ready call to add the class when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar_table .option .my_website_link').each(function(){
        // logic for adding the class to the page the user is on
        if(XXXXXXXXX){
             $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The links are dynamically generated based on a particular user of the site, so hard-coding the solution is probably not the best approach. Thanks for the comments so far.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

HTML

```
<table class="sidebar_table">
    <tr class="option">
        <td class="select page1">image</td>
        <td><a href="my_website_link.html#page1">A Link</a></td>
        <td class="select page2">image</td>
        <td><a href="my_website_anotherlink.html#page2">A Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

script

```
...
var page = window.location.hash;

$('.option').find('a').each(
    function (i, el) {
        if ($(el).hasClass('page')) {
            $(el).addClass('selected');
        }
    };
);
...
```

...or use php or local storage.

edit: OK, I just realized this is very similar to what circusdei suggested. Then OP says "links are dynamically generated" Well, most pages are dynamically generated, right? So how about dynamically plugging some keyword into the link's hash, the td's class, and the script?

Comment: like the idea for local storage...keep forgetting that's the future.